# Why does this first Haskell function FAIL to handle infinite lists, while this second snippet SUCCEEDS with infinite lists?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

I have two Haskell functions, both of which seem very similar to me. But the first one FAILS against infinite lists, and the second one SUCCEEDS against infinite lists. I have been trying for hours to nail down exactly why that is, but to no avail.

Both snippets are a re-implementation of the "words" function in Prelude. Both work fine against finite lists.

Here's the version that does NOT handle infinite lists:

```
myWords_FailsOnInfiniteList :: String -> [String]
myWords_FailsOnInfiniteList string = foldr step [] (dropWhile charIsSpace string)
   where 
      step space ([]:xs)      | charIsSpace space = []:xs    
      step space (x:xs)       | charIsSpace space = []:x:xs
      step space []           | charIsSpace space = []
      step char (x:xs)                            = (char : x) : xs
      step char []                                = [[char]]
```

Here's the version that DOES handle infinite lists:

```
myWords_anotherReader :: String -> [String]
myWords_anotherReader xs = foldr step [""] xs
   where 
      step x result | not . charIsSpace $ x = [x:(head result)]++tail result
                    | otherwise             = []:result
```

Note: "charIsSpace" is merely a renaming of Char.isSpace.

The following interpreter session illustrates that the first one fails against an infinite list while the second one succeeds.

```
*Main> take 5 (myWords_FailsOnInfiniteList  (cycle "why "))
*** Exception: stack overflow

*Main> take 5 (myWords_anotherReader (cycle "why "))
["why","why","why","why","why"]
```

**EDIT: Thanks to the responses below, I believe I understand now. Here are my conclusions and the revised code:**

**Conclusions:**

1. The biggest culprit in my first attempt were the 2 equations that started with "step space []" and "step char []". **Matching the second parameter of the step function against [] is a no-no**, because it forces the whole 2nd arg to be evaluated (but with a caveat to be explained below).
2. At one point, I had thought (++) might evaluate its right-hand argument later than cons would, somehow. So, I thought I might fix the problem by changing " = (char:x):xs" to "= [char : x] ++ xs". But that was **incorrect**.
3. At one point, I thought that pattern matching the second arg against (x:xs) would cause the function to fail against infinite lists. I was *almost* right about this, but not quite! Evaluating the second arg against (x:xs), as I do in a pattern match above, *WILL* cause some recursion. It will "turn the crank" until it hits a ":" (aka, "cons"). If that never happened, then my function would not succeed against an infinite list. However, *in this particular case*, everything is OK because my function will eventually encounter a space, at which point a "cons" will occur. And the evaluation triggered by matching against (x:xs) will stop right there, avoiding the infinite recursion. At that point, the "x" will be matched, but the xs will remain a thunk, so there's no problem. (Thanks to Ganesh for really helping me grasp that).
4. In general, you can **mention** the second arg all you want, as long as you don't **force evaluation of it**. If you've matched against x:xs, then you can mention xs all you want, as long as you don't force evaluation of it.

So, here's the revised code. I usually try to avoid head and tail, merely because they are partial functions, and also because I need practice writing the pattern matching equivalent.

```
myWords :: String -> [String]
myWords string = foldr step [""] (dropWhile charIsSpace string)
   where 
      step space acc | charIsSpace space = "":acc
      step char (x:xs)                   = (char:x):xs
      step _ []                          = error "this should be impossible"
```

This correctly works against infinite lists. Note there's no head, tail or (++) operator in sight.

**Now, for an important caveat:**
When I first wrote the corrected code, I did not have the 3rd equation, which matches against "step _ []". As a result, I received the warning about non-exhaustive pattern matches. Obviously, it is a good idea to avoid that warning.

But I thought I was going to have a problem. I already mentioned above that *it is not OK to pattern match the second arg against []*. But I would have to do so in order to get rid of the warning.

**However, when I added the "step _ []" equation, everything was fine! There was still no problem with infinite lists!**. Why?

**Because the 3rd equation in the corrected code IS NEVER REACHED!**

In fact, consider the following BROKEN version. It is EXACTLY the SAME as the correct code, except that I have moved the pattern for empty list up above the other patterns:

```
myWords_brokenAgain :: String -> [String]
myWords_brokenAgain string = foldr step [""] (dropWhile charIsSpace string)
   where 
      step _ []                              = error "this should be impossible"
      step space acc | charIsSpace space     = "":acc
      step char (x:xs)                       = (char:x):xs
```

We're back to stack overflow, because the first thing that happens when step is called is that the interpreter checks to see if equation number one is a match. To do so, it must see if the second arg is []. To do that, it must evaluate the second arg.

Moving the equation down BELOW the other equations ensures that the 3rd equation is never attempted, because either the first or the second pattern *always matches*. The 3rd equation is merely there to dispense with the non-exhaustive pattern warning.

This has been a great learning experience. Thanks to everyone for your help.

Comment: Just a little clarification to conclusion 3: "Evaluate" in Haskell really means "evaluate to WHNF (weak head normal form)".  Disregarding bang (strict, !) and irrefutable (lazy, ~) patterns, pattern matching only forces evaluation until constructors and constants are satisfied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Others have pointed out the problem, which is that step always evaluates its second argument before producing any output at all, yet its second argument will ultimately depend on the result of another invocation of step when the foldr is applied to an infinite list.

It doesn't have to be written this way, but your second version is kind of ugly because it relies on the initial argument to step having a particular format and it's quite hard to see that the head/tail will never go wrong. (I'm not even 100% certain that they won't!)

What you should do is restructure the first version so it produces output without depending on the input list in at least some situations. In particular we can see that when the character is not a space, there's always at least one element in the output list. So delay the pattern-matching on the second argument until after producing that first element. The case where the character is a space will still be dependent on the list, but that's fine because the only way that case can infinitely recurse is if you pass in an infinite list of spaces, in which case not producing any output and going into a loop is the expected behaviour for words (what else could it do?)

Comment: Excellent. In particular, the guideline seems to be "delay the pattern-matching on the second argument until after producing that first element". I'm going to try that and will report back with the results.

Comment: Alright, Ganesh, I have given it a shot and I think I understand. Would you please look at my revised question and let me know if you think I'm incorrect about anything? Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear on a point that I'm not sure you've grasped: matching the second argument against either [] or (x:xs) forces its evaluation a little bit (specifically, into either a [] or a cons :-). Your revised code works because it doesn't force the list if the character is a space.

Just to add a bit more information into the mix, check out "lazy patterns", which are introduced with a ~. If you use one in your second line of definition, then it won't force the list either despite being a match against (x:xs).

Comment: Ganesh, you're absolutely right. This was a key point for me, and I am grateful for you pointing it out. It is not correct for me to say that it is "perfectly fine" to match the 2nd arg against (x:xs), because there are cases when that would NOT be ok. It is only OK here because there are cases when matching against (x:xs) won't cause infinite recursion because it will lead to a space. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try expanding the expression by hand:

```
 take 5 (myWords_FailsOnInfiniteList  (cycle "why "))
 take 5 (foldr step [] (dropWhile charIsSpace (cycle "why ")))
 take 5 (foldr step [] (dropWhile charIsSpace ("why " ++ cycle "why ")))
 take 5 (foldr step [] ("why " ++ cycle "why "))
 take 5 (step 'w' (foldr step [] ("hy " ++ cycle "why ")))
 take 5 (step 'w' (step 'h' (foldr step [] ("y " ++ cycle "why "))))
```

What's the next expansion? You should see that in order to pattern match for `step`, you need to know whether it's the empty list or not. In order to find that out, you have to evaluate it, at least a little bit. But that second term happens to be a `foldr` reduction by the very function you're pattern matching for. In other words, the step function cannot look at its arguments without calling itself, and so you have an infinite recursion.

Contrast that with an expansion of your second function:

```
myWords_anotherReader (cycle "why ")
foldr step [""] (cycle "why ")
foldr step [""] ("why " ++ cycle "why ")
step 'w' (foldr step [""] ("hy " ++ cycle "why ")
let result = foldr step [""] ("hy " ++ cycle "why ") in
    ['w':(head result)] ++ tail result
let result = step 'h' (foldr step [""] ("y " ++ cycle "why ") in
    ['w':(head result)] ++ tail result
```

You can probably see that this expansion will continue until a space is reached. Once a space is reached, "head result" will obtain a value, and you will have produced the first element of the answer.

I suspect that this second function will overflow for infinite strings that don't contain any spaces. Can you see why?

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I had actually broken it down like this, but I was overlooking the fact that pattern matching itself was causing the second arg to be eval'd. And I do see why it would overflow for a string with no spaces. But, is there a way to implement myWords without using head or tail?

Comment: Have a look at the prelude's "span" function and see if you can rewrite that as a foldr.

Comment: I figured out how to do it without head and tail before I saw your response. But I will do the exercise you suggest. I appreciate the suggestion and am looking forward to it.

Comment: @Apocalisp, would you please take a look at the corrected code and the list of conclusions I've reached? I edited the question and added that information, and would love to find out if you feel I've missed anything or reached incorrect conclusions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The second version does not actually evaluate `result` until *after* it has started producing part of its own answer.  The first version evaluates `result` *immediately* by pattern matching on it.

The key with these infinite lists is that you have to produce *something* before you start demanding list elements so that the output can always "stay ahead" of the input.

(I feel like this explanation is not very clear, but it's the best I can do.)

Comment: OK, thanks. Follow-up question: It seems that everything that can be produced with (++) can also be produced with cons (at least in this example). However, if I understand correctly, cons will eval its right-most args first, whereas (++) won't. So when dealing with infinite lists, it seems sometimes we would need to choose (++) over cons. Is that correct?

Comment: @Charlie: I don't understand what you are trying to say.  `head ((cycle [0])++undefined)` and `head (undefined:undefined)` both work just fine.  (Of course, forcing the result of the second expression is undefined...)

Comment: Yes, I see now that you're right @ephemient. There is no material difference between cons and ++ in terms of evaluation time. I had a number of "guesses" of why my code wasn't handling infinite lists, most of which I think I've now debunked. I think the light bulb has come on now.

Comment: @Norman: I have corrected my code. The corrected code is now in the question, along with a list of conclusions I have reached. Would you please take a look and let me know if there are any incorrect conclusions there, or if you have anything to add? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The library function `foldr` has this implementation (or similar):

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f k (x:xs) = f x (foldr f k xs)
foldr _ k _ = k
```

The result of `myWords_FailsOnInfiniteList` depends on the result of `foldr` which depends on the result of `step` which depends on the result of the inner `foldr` which depends on ... and so on an infinite list, `myWords_FailsOnInfiniteList` will use up an infinite amount of space and time before producing its first word.

The `step` function in `myWords_anotherReader` does not require the result of the inner `foldr` until after it has produced the first letter of the first word.  Unfortunately, as Apocalisp says, it uses O(length of first word) space before it produces the next word, because as the first word is being produced, the tail thunk keeps growing `tail ([...] ++ tail ([...] ++ tail (...)))`.

---

In contrast, compare to

```
myWords :: String -> [String]
myWords = myWords' . dropWhile isSpace where
    myWords' [] = []
    myWords' string =
        let (part1, part2) = break isSpace string
        in part1 : myWords part2
```

using library functions which may be defined as

```
break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
break p = span $ not . p

span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
span p xs = (takeWhile p xs, dropWhile p xs)

takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile p (x:xs) | p x = x : takeWhile p xs
takeWhile _ _ = []

dropWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
dropWhile p (x:xs) | p x = dropWhile p xs
dropWhile _ xs = xs
```

Notice that producing the intermediate results is never held up by future computation, and only O(1) space is needed as each element of the result is made available for consumption.

---

#### Addendum

> So, here's the revised code. I usually try to avoid head and tail, merely because they are partial functions, and also because I need practice writing the pattern matching equivalent.
>
> ```
> myWords :: String -> [String]
> myWords string = foldr step [""] (dropWhile charIsSpace string)
>    where 
>       step space acc | charIsSpace space = "":acc
>       step char (x:xs)                   = (char:x):xs
>       step _ []                          = error "this should be impossible"
> ```

(Aside: You may not care, but the `words "" == []` from the library, but your `myWords "" = [""]`.  Similar issue with trailing spaces.)

Looks much-improved over `myWords_anotherReader`, and is pretty good for a `foldr`-based solution.

```
\n -> tail $ myWords $ replicate n 'a' ++ " b"
```

It's not possible to do better than O(n) time, but both `myWords_anotherReader` and `myWords` take O(n) space here.  This may be inevitable given the use of `foldr`.

Worse,

```
\n -> head $ head $ myWords $ replicate n 'a' ++ " b"
```

`myWords_anotherReader` was O(1) but the new `myWords` is O(n), because pattern matching `(x:xs)` requires the further result.

You can work around this with

```
myWords :: String -> [String]
myWords = foldr step [""] . dropWhile isSpace
   where 
      step space acc | isSpace space = "":acc
      step char ~(x:xs)              = (char:x):xs
```

The `~` introduces an "irrefutable pattern".  Irrefutable patterns never fail and do not force immediate evaluation.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I was actually working on an exercise that specifically wanted me to implement it using foldr. I had implemented it with break and explicit recursion before that.

Comment: ephemient, I'd love to get your thoughts and any corrections to the revised code and the conclusions I've reached. I edited my question with that info and would love to hear any feedback you have.